# Earning the Editor Badge

Tags: discussion, editing, badges

I'm a new user and did a search to see if this topic was already covered, but found nothing, so forgive me if this has already been mentioned.

I obtained the editor badge when I went to edit a post for a trivial issue of wording (not spelling) but then decided I was being pedantic and left the editor, post unchanged.

My question is should the editor badge be handed out for first time edits even if no edit actually occurred?

Some people may consider even being willing to perform an edit something worthy of rewarding a badge for, something that should be encouraged. Whats the community think, or is there a policy that I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the editor badge for editing [your own answer](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/6486/problems-with-character-development/6502#6502), something I was unaware was possible. However, [a little digging](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66962/33-rep-and-editor-badge) shows that this is indeed the case: If a user performs an edit of any sort, even to their own posts, the system will award them the editor badge.

Comment: The issue was that I got the editor badge originally because I hit the edit button but then decided not to submit my edit. A badge essentially for nothing.

Comment: Was this editing on your own answer or on another one? because [this](http://writers.stackexchange.com/posts/6502/revisions) is an impressively extensive edit.

Comment: Also noteworthy: scripts sometimes run a bit delayed. @JamesF. You might have triggered the editor badge award on a different edit?

Comment: I recall receiving the badge before making another edit so the whole matter is odd.